# Convert SQL to Linq where there is in clause

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I would like to know how to convert SQL query listed below into LINQ query in VB.

```
SELECT FacilityID 
FROM tblFacilityProjects 
WHERE FreedomEnabled = True and ProjectID in (840,841,842)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it I think:

```
Dim projectIds = New Integer() {840, 841, 842}
Dim result = From proj In db.tblFacilityProjects _
             Where proj.FreedomEnabled = True AndAlso _
                   projectIds.Contains(proj.ProjectID) _
             Select FacilityID
```

Comment: Better than couple of examples that took a longer route, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**IN Query in SQL**

```
SELECT [Id], [UserId]
FROM [Tablename]
WHERE [UserId] IN (2, 3)
```

**IN Query in LINQ**

Makes use of the `Contains` function of VB.

```
Dim coll As Integer() = {2, 3}
Dim user = From u In tablename Where coll.Contains(u.UserId.Value) New 
From {
    u.id, u.userid
}
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/4479/sql-in-and-not-in-clause-in-linq-using-vb-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of your project ID

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
list.Add(840)
list.Add(841)
list.Add(842)
```

Now you have to use this in LINQ.

```
dim facilityId = from fp in tblFacilityProjects 
                 where FreedomEnabled == true
                 where list.Contains(ProjectID)
                 select new
                 {
                   FacilityID=fp.FacilityID
                 }
```

There must be some tweaks you may need to do for VB.net .